# PHP5 xsl install

Tags: php

just a quick question, Im running PHP5 on my debian server (squeeze), due to some magento extension requirement, I need to install the php5-xls module, this is a PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT, so, after a "apt-get install php5-xls", obviously I get:

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

The following extra packages will be installed:

libapache2-mod-php5 libxslt1.1 php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt 
php5-mysql

Suggested packages:
  php-pear

**The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libxslt1.1 php5-xsl
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-mysql
7 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 59 not upgraded.**

Need to get 6,953 kB of archives.
After this operation, 606 kB of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue [Y/n]?

I've used Linux for some time and Ive seen things crashing down for simple things like this, I just want to know how much am I risking my current PHP installation by hitting the "y" key....we are running online-shops here..is there a more secure way ?

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Yes, things can go wrong. That's why you do backups and testing.

Answer (score 1):

Then install a development server. We can not assure you things will go right. As I personally think, it will go fine. It upgrades previous installs, and installs 2 new packages.

Comment: Thanks, as the development server is fedora, and the production one is debian, I think I would need to risk it, is there a way to backup the PHP installation? I dont think of an simple way  way but maybe u know...thanks !