# Install of PHP 5.5.8 failing --with-xsl

Tags: php, apache

If anyone can help me out here I'd really appreciate it. I'm trying to install PHP 5.5.8 and my configure statement is as follows:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php 
--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs
--with-libdir=lib64
--with-tidy=/usr 
--with-gd 
--with-png-dir=/usr/local 
--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local
--with-mysqli 
--with-mysql
--with-xsl
--with-curl 
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local 
--enable-soap
--with-libxml-dir=/usr/local 
--enable-mbstring 
--with-ldap 
--with-pear
```

and it exits "make" with a string of errors like:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/libexslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewChild@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlParserGetDirectory@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDictQLookup@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewText@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `htmlSetMetaEncoding@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/libexslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathPopBoolean@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

I have three RHEL 6 servers all with same versions of PHP and Apache (2.4.7) and the install works fine on two but not on the third, where the install only works if I omit the "--with-xsl" . Has anyone any ideas on what I might be missing here? I really need to get this working and nothing I've tried so far makes any difference.

Comment: Sorry, only wild guessing, but just because it's easy to test: you might try `yum install libxml2-devel` and then try compiling php again. I'd find it strange though if it worked since `configure` should(?) alert you when the library isn't there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP5 xsl install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190086/php5-xsl-install)